# Parametric Equations for semicircle

Tags: calculus

How does one find the parametric equation for the semicircle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$, $y > 0$, using as parameter the slope $t = \frac{dy}{dx}$ of the tangent to the curve at $(x, y)$?

The solution given is $x = \frac{-at}{\sqrt{1 + t^2}}$, $y = {a}{\sqrt{1 + t^2}}$, $-\infty < t < \infty$. But I cannot see how this solution has been obtained.

This is what I have so far. Use implicit differentiation to get $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{- x}{y}$. But where does one go from there?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: yes! It should be that.

Comment: This has the tone of a command and not a question.

Comment: Duly noted and rephrased. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use implicit differentiation.  You get $2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.  Replace $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with $t$ and then solve for $x$.  Next, plug in the solution to $x^2+y^2=a^2$.  Solve the resulting equation for $y$ and plug that back into your solution for $x$.  Boom, done.

Comment: Thank you! How did you know that you can just replace $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with t?

Comment: In your question statement you demand that $t=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I do demand that. Why couldn't we just plug in the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into the usual parametric equations of a circle to get something like this: $x = a cos (\frac{dy}{dx})$ and $y = a sin(\frac{dy}{dx})$  for $0 \leq t \leq  \pi$?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The "usual" parametric equations of a circle are $x=a\cos(\theta),y=a\sin(\theta)$. By the usual polar conversion formula we have that $\tan(\theta)=y/x$. The slope $t$ of the tangent line is perpendicular to the line thru the origin with angle $\theta$, and thus satisfies $\tan(\theta)=-1/t$. Now $\theta=\text{arctan}(-1/t)$ which means $x=a\cos(\text{arctan}(-1/t))$ and $y=a\sin(\text{arctan}(-1/t))$, maybe with a $\pm$ decision to be made. But such formulas are rather nasty and should be simplified. At this point we are doing more work than necessary.